# Snip & Sketch, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

As you press Win+Shift+S (for snipping) the screen gets greyed out.

EDIT: The screen portion in the clipboard KEEPS this DIMMED, FADED look

I ASSUME that the result of the snipping is meant to NOT HAVE THAT -grey-out- look.

Anyone have a remedy, workaround for this? (Other than using other SW).

*(I have long used "Hypersnap", but it has been removed from being allowed within the Company SW. Snip & Sketch is a LOOONG jump back in time.)*

---

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working as designed. You get the yellow border, then inside that area you click and drag to select an area to put on the clipboard. Once you release the mouse button, the screen is restored to "normal", and you have your selected item on your clipboard, with a notification in the taskbar. What exactly are you expecting to happen, outside of that?

Comment: That is entirely normal behavior - Windows 10 and 11. Screen brightens to normal after selection.

Comment: Please Check above once again. I simply forgot to type in the problem.

Comment: If, after you open the screen shot, it still seems all gray, start by running DISM / SFC .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: The snip is NOT supposed to have the same faded look. Please upload pictures showing this.

Comment: Oh, if this is a business computer you need to talk to your company IT folks.

Comment: Not likely to be something local "IT" can remedy as it clearly is a Microsoft product malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

> The snip is NOT supposed to have the same faded look. Please upload pictures showing this.

This zip file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ud_0fsTGqqjqv8_x-wRP8AzeUheBW8vP/view?usp=sharing

contains three versions of the same thing:

- gqq.PNG screen shot using good old Snipping Tool;
- gqq.jpg screen shot using newfangled Snip & Sketch;
- gqq_copy.jpg JPEG copy of gqq.PNG made with Photoshop - no other processing.

The Snip & Sketch screen shot has dim colors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hard to see what the Bot is getting at. I did screenshots of the same thing two ways and got different results, one obviously better than the other. I also converted the good one into a JPEG to make sure it wasn't a JPG vs PNG thing. Not a lot more to say.